# Viewing Assembly level code from Visual C++ project 

Tags: visual-c++

Which project setting would let me see the generated assembly level code in Microsoft Visual C++ 2005?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project Property Page > C/C++ > Output Files > Assembler Output (then take your pick).

Answer (score 1):

if debugging then view->disassembly.